# Rails ActionMailer Mail Not Delivered From 3.2 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I upgraded my app from 3.0 to 3.1 to 3.2 (per the recommendations). All specs and scenarios pass and they test the email sent pretty deeply. What happens is that the email appears to be sent if I look at my `maillog` and the correct templates appear to be rendered, but no mail is actually delivered to the user.

This code worked perfectly in the 3.0 version of this app. I'm hoping someone can spot out what I'm missing. The first several files I've shown in the code below are configuration files. Again, this stuff worked fine in previous deploys. I'm baffled.

The "controller mixin" is a module that is mixed into any controller that wants to send mail. The controllers do almost exactly the same thing so all I have to change is the mailers and the views.

I'm stumped how to proceed even debugging this. I know I can specify more detailed smtp settings but this worked fine before and it is resilient once I prop this in DNS, not relying on a particular hostname.

Any thoughts are most appreciated!

production.rb

```
# other non-mailer stuff elided.

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => `hostname` }
ActionMailer::Base.default(:charset => 'utf-8')
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
```

config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
require 'development_mail_interceptor'

Mail.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if Rails.env.development?
```

lib/development_mail_interceptor.rb

```
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.subject = "[#{message.to}] #{message.subject}"
    message.to = "my.address@gmail.com"
  end
end
```

Controller mixin (this is in a module that is mixed into controllers that do mail):

```
def send_detail_email
  @detail_email = @mailer_klass.sent(@ar_obj, session)
end

def send_confirm_email
  @confirm_email = @mailer_klass.confirm(@ar_obj, session)
end

def send_email
  send_detail_email
  # Field naming is inconsistent, so sniff out the contact type
  contact_type = ''
  contact_type = @ar_obj.contact if @ar_obj.respond_to?(:contact)
  contact_type = @ar_obj.best_contact_method if @ar_obj.respond_to?(:best_contact_method)
  contact_type = @ar_obj.contact_method if @ar_obj.respond_to?(:contact_method)

  # If no contact type, then it's probably assumed a user object's email
  contact_type = 'email' if @ar_obj.respond_to?(:user) &&
                          !@ar_obj.respond_to?(:contact) &&
                          !@ar_obj.respond_to?(:best_contact_method) &&
                          !@ar_obj.respond_to?(:contact_method)

  send_confirm_email if contact_type == 'email'
end
```